# Pandas: filling placeholders in string column

Tags: python, pandas, string-formatting

I am working with a pandas DataFrame looking as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['There are # people', '3', np.nan], ['# out of # people are there', 'Five', 'eight'],
     ['Only # are here', '2', np.nan], ['The rest is at home', np.nan, np.nan]])
```

resulting in:

```
    0                            1     2
0   There are # people           3     NaN
1   # out of # people are there  Five  eight
2   Only # are here              2     NaN
3   The rest is at home          NaN   NaN
```

I would like to replace the `#` placeholders with the varying strings in columns 1 and 2, resulting in:

```
0   There are 3 people
1   Five out of eight people are there
2   Only 2 are here
3   The rest is at home
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more concise way to do it.

```
cols = df.columns
df[cols[0]] = df.apply(lambda x: x[cols[0]].replace('#',str(x[cols[1]]),1) if x[cols[1]]!=np.NaN else x,axis=1)
print(df.apply(lambda x: x[cols[0]].replace('#',str(x[cols[2]]),1) if x[cols[2]]!=np.NaN else x,axis=1))
```

---

```
Out[12]:
0                    There are 3 people
1    Five out of eight people are there
2                       Only 2 are here
3                   The rest is at home
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

If you need to do this for even more columns

```
cols = df.columns
for i in range(1, len(cols)):
    df[cols[0]] = df.apply(lambda x: x[cols[0]].replace('#',str(x[cols[i]]),1) if x[cols[i]]!=np.NaN else x,axis=1)
print(df[cols[0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using string format

```
df=df.replace({'#':'%s',np.nan:'NaN'},regex=True)

l=[]

for x , y in df.iterrows():
    if  y[2]=='NaN' and y[1]=='NaN':
        l.append(y[0])
    elif y[2]=='NaN':
        l.append(y[0] % (y[1]))
    else:
        l.append(y[0] % (y[1], y[2]))
l
Out[339]: 
['There are 3 people',
 'Five out of eight people are there',
 'Only 2 are here',
 'The rest is at home']
```

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of `df.apply`

Comment: However, after some time testing, I've found mine to be a tad bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

A generic replace function in case you may have more values to add:
Replaces all instances if a given character in a string using a list of values (just two in your case but it can handle more)

```
def replace_hastag(text, values, replace_char='#'):
    for v in values:
        if v is np.NaN:
            return text
        else:
            text = text.replace(replace_char, str(v), 1)
    return text


df['text'] = df.apply(lambda r: replace_hastag(r[0], values=[r[1], r[2]]), axis=1)
```

Result

```
In [79]: df.text
Out[79]:
0                    There are 3 people
1    Five out of eight people are there
2                       Only 2 are here
3                   The rest is at home
Name: text, dtype: object
```